# Hide products having a specific product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

We use the following code to hide products having categories "uncategorized":

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query');
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {
    if (!$q->is_main_query()) return;
    if (!$q->is_post_type_archive()) return;
  $q->set('tax_query', array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
      'field'    => 'slug',
      'terms'    => 'ukategorisert',
      'operator' => 'NOT IN',
    )
  ));
    remove_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query');
}
```

But for some reason, the archive ends up showing a different number of products on each page. It seems like the products are hidden, but still counted as products in the pagination?

We can't find a reason or solution for this problem. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `pre_get_posts` hooked function, you should use one of the related dedicated Woocommerce action and filter hooks.

Try this instead:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'custom_product_query_tax_query', 10, 2 );
function custom_product_query_tax_query( $tax_query, $query ) {
    if( is_admin() ) return $tax_query;

    // HERE Define your product category SLUGs to be excluded
    $terms = array( 'ukategorisert' ); // SLUGs only

    // The taxonomy for Product Categories
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';

    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'field'    => 'slug', // Or 'name' or 'term_id'
        'terms'    => $terms,
        'operator' => 'NOT IN', // Excluded
    );

    return $tax_query;
}
```

This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). It should work.